# How to increment the objects key values using set interval

Tags: javascript

Here's what I am trying: I have an object and I'm trying increment the values by 0.01 & 1 using `setInterval`

my object

```
 var data = {
  timer: {
        "num": "0.1",
        "perfection": "0",
    }
 }
```

here `num` value has to be increased by 0.1 & `perfection` value by 1 and if perfection's value reaches 100 then it has to stop using set interval

```js
var data = {
  timer: {
      "num": "0.0",
      "perfection": "0"
  }
}
var info = [];
var maxValue=101;

setInterval(loop,2000)
    
function loop(){
 for(var i = 0; i < maxValue; i++) {
     data['timer']['perfection'] = i; 
       console.log(data)
  }
}
```

Comment: If you know you want to use setInterval, where is your code  attempt to do so?

Comment: as said, use `setInterval` (you don't need a for loop), store it in a variable and when the values reach the amount you want, clear that interval.

Comment: @CalvinNunes updated code please chek

Comment: Is there something specific you're having difficulty with?  You seem to know how to use `setInterval` and how to change object properties.

Comment: @freedomn-m but not able to increment values of the object

Comment: you don't need a `for` loop you need just a variable keeping track of how many times `setInterval` called the function to increment, when it reaches 100, use `clearInterval()` on the variable that holds the interval`

Comment: The problem is that your "values" are strings, so when you `+1` or whatever, it goes "011111.." rather than "0,1,2,3".  Make the original object values numbers:  `var data = { time : { num: 0.0, perfection: 0 } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop, you need just a variable keeping track of how many times `setInterval` called the function to increment, when it reaches 100, use clearInterval() on the variable that holds the interval.

 Using just `data['timer']['perfection'] = i;` will not increment `data.timer.num` it will just set the `data.timer.perfection` to the exact same value as `i`. You need to explicitely increment both properties, see below

Also, I changed the values on the object to numbers, if you can't do this, you'll need to parse the values, otherwise it will concatenate (`"0" + 1 = "01"`)

```js
var data = {
  timer: {
      "num": 0.0,
      "perfection": 0
  }
}
var i = 0;
var maxValue = 100;

var interval = setInterval(increment, 100)
    
function increment(){  
   data.timer.perfection += 1;   
   data.timer.num += 0.1; 
   console.clear()
   console.log(data) 
   i++;
   if (i >= maxValue) {
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log("finish")
   }
}
```

And as you can see, the JS decimal value can be a little "broken", because adding 0.1 may make your `num` to be something like 0.299999999 instead of 0.3, for example. (further read: [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript))

Answer (score 2):

> unable to increment values of the object

The original values are strings, so these (ideally) need to be numbers to be able to increment.

```
var data = {
  timer: {
    "num": 0.0,
    "perfection": 0
  }
}
```

You can then increment with

data.timer.perfection += 1

The next issue you'll have is when to stop the `setInterval` - this can be done with `clearInterval` using the return value of the original setInterval.

Updated code:

```js
var data = {
  timer: {
    "num": 0.0,
    "perfection": 0
  }
}

// reduced values for demo purpose
var maxValue = 10;
var intervalId = setInterval(loop, 200) 

function loop() {
  data.timer.num += 0.1
  data.timer.perfection += 1
  if (data.timer.perfection >= maxValue) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    console.log(data)
  }
}
```